# Dynamic info window size ios google maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I'm creating custom info window onto google maps like this:

```
NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoView" owner:self options:nil];
InfoView *mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
UIView *subview = mainView.subviews[0];
//setup content
return subview;
```

This way it works fine, but I cannot add any constraints because then it fills up the whole screen and becomes blank. So I decided to do this without autolayout.

My content is few labels one below the other. In same cases, text cannot fit single line and then label frame should increase. In the same time, whole view frame must be also increased and views below must be offset properly. I've made a method to do this, everything is changing except the info window view frame itself. In the logs, I can see frame has changed, but on the screen, it has original size and text is outside of it.

I even tried just changing info window frame and still no effect - it doesn't change at all.

I've also tried calling `[subview layoutIfNeeded]` and `[subview layoutSubviews]`.

So, how can I make info window with dynamic size?

edit:

Whole code as @Milan requested:

```
- (UIView *_Nullable) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoContents: (GMSMarker *)marker {
    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PortView" owner:self options:nil];
    PortView *mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
    UIView *subview = mainView.subviews[0];
    mainView.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.origin.x, mainView.frame.origin.y, mainView.frame.size.width, mainView.frame.size.height + 40) //increase frame size doesn't work
    mainView.titleLabel.text = portSzukany.name;
    return subview;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the GMSMapViewDelegate and return the info view from below method:

```
- (UIView *GMS_NULLABLE_PTR)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker;
```

As per description given for the method, "The returned UIView must not have bounds greater than 500 points on either dimension."

Comment: I'm already using this. The problem is I must use strict view size, size won't change is content is shorter or longer.

Comment: Can you paste the code, how you are creating dynamic size of view

Comment: I'm loading view from xib and modify it's frame to adjust size. Problem is it doesn't change anything. Constraints also doesn't work with it. The only way to achieve this is to build whole view from scratch in code.

Comment: Yes I read that, and this is what I am asking how are you making it through code. That could be an error prone.

Comment: See my edit. Changing main view frame just doesn't work.

Comment: You are using the wrong delegate method my friend. Use the one I mentioned.

Comment: Ok, it worked! The thing is now I lost "balloon" style background because it's work just plain rectangle. But I guess I can work it out somehow with my own images.

Comment: Yes, you have to write your own logic or there would be already available code to make balloon.

Answer (score 0):

When i faced with this problem, i find the only way to update infoWindow's frame: dismissing info window and showing it again like this:

```
let m = mapView?.selectedMarker
mapView?.selectedMarker = nil
mapView?.selectedMarker = m
```

Or you can just use SMCalloutView, it compatible with Google Maps.

I think Google Maps don't use system layouts for rendering. It use OpenGL or something.

Full source (Its swift code, I hope this will not be a problem for you )

```
import GoogleMaps


class GMapsViewController: UIViewController {
    let CalloutYOffset:CGFloat = 50.0

    var mapView = GMSMapView.map(
        withFrame: CGRect.zero,
        camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
    ),
    infoWindowWidth:CGFloat = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        infoWindowWidth = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.frame.size.width ?? 0 - 30
        //maps
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.delegate = self
        self.view = mapView
        //markers
        let marker1 = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20))
        marker1.title = "Sydney"
        marker1.snippet = "Custom"
        marker1.map = mapView

        mapView.selectedMarker = marker1

        updateInfoWIndowText()
    }

    var infoWindowText = "tqweqweqweqweqwe"
    func updateInfoWIndowText(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:  (DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(2000)), execute: {
            print("UPDATE INFO WINDOW TEXT")
            self.infoWindowText = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

            weak var mapView = self.mapView
            //dismissing info window and showing it
            let m = mapView?.selectedMarker
            mapView?.selectedMarker = nil
            mapView?.selectedMarker = m
        })
    }

}

extension GMapsViewController:GMSMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

        let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, w: infoWindowWidth, h: 0))
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        for _ in 0...3 {
            let lab = UILabel()
            lab.numberOfLines = 0
            lab.text = infoWindowText
            lab.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(lab)
        }
        stackView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: stackView,
            attribute: .width,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: .notAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: infoWindowWidth))
        stackView.h = stackView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        return stackView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        mapView.selectedMarker = marker
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long you are not setting up any frames, it should scale correctly in height. It took me a lot of tries to realize this.

The width though will be full width. I am experimenting with this still, but if you want to add some margins/paddings to the side of the infoWindow in relation to the device width, I think the margins must come directly from the nib file and not trying to set frame width directly to the mainView.

I think once you resize the frame, some views won't display correctly, like for instance some views might be cut off because in change of width a label had to wrap into 2 lines. Then once the view is returned then it is already too late as the view for info window is converted into an image for google maps. Any layoutsubview methods will not affect that info window anymore.

So either you compute the frame correctly, which is very hard to do, specially because you can't render and get frames correctly or you set up everything before hand in the .xib file and just return that as it comes without altering its frame!